How to Resolve IndexError: tuple index out of range for my python code
I've been trying to make noise filter integrated with Artificial Intelligence. But when compiled the following code, i encountered the error below. How can i resolve it?
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, BatchNormalization, Reshape, Input
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

# MFCC özelliklerini çıkarma fonksiyonu
def extract_mfcc(audio, sample_rate, n_mfcc=20, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512):
    mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=n_mfcc, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length)
    return mfcc.T  # Zaman eksenine uygun hale getir

# CNN modeli oluşturma
def create_cnn_model(input_shape):
    model = Sequential([
        Input(shape=input_shape),
        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"),
        BatchNormalization(),
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same"),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding="same"),
        BatchNormalization(),
        MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding="same"),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        BatchNormalization(),
        Dense(np.prod(input_shape[:-1]), activation='linear'),
        Reshape(input_shape[:-1])  # Çıkışı orijinal şekle döndür
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
    return model

# Gürültüsüz ve gürültülü ses dosyalarını yükle
clean_file_path = "denoised.wav"
noisy_file_path = "CPLT_140knt.wav"

clean_audio, sample_rate_clean = librosa.load(clean_file_path, sr=None)
noisy_audio, sample_rate_noisy = librosa.load(noisy_file_path, sr=None)

# Uzunlukları eşitle
min_length = min(len(clean_audio), len(noisy_audio))
clean_audio = clean_audio[:min_length]
noisy_audio = noisy_audio[:min_length]

# MFCC çıkarma
clean_mfcc = extract_mfcc(clean_audio, sample_rate_clean)
noisy_mfcc = extract_mfcc(noisy_audio, sample_rate_noisy)

# Veri seti oluşturma
X = np.expand_dims(noisy_mfcc, axis=-1)  # Gürültülü MFCC
y = np.expand_dims(clean_mfcc, axis=-1)  # Gürültüsüz MFCC

# Eğitim ve test veri setlerini ayırma
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# CNN giriş boyutunu belirleme
_, height, width = X_train.shape
channels = 1
input_shape = (height, width, channels)

# CNN modeli oluşturma
model = create_cnn_model(input_shape)

# Modeli eğitme
print("Model eğitiliyor...")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=250, batch_size=128, verbose=1)

# Gürültüyü temizleme
predicted_mfcc = model.predict(X_test)

# MFCC'den ses sinyalini yeniden oluşturma
def reconstruct_audio_from_mfcc(mfcc, sr, n_fft=2048, hop_length=512):
    mel_spec = librosa.feature.inverse.mfcc_to_mel(mfcc.T)
    mel_spec = np.maximum(mel_spec, 1e-10)  # Negatif veya sıfır değerleri önlemek için küçük bir minimum belirle
    # Mel-spektrogramdan ses sinyali oluşturma
    reconstructed_audio = librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio(mel_spec, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length)
    return reconstructed_audio

# İlk test örneğini yeniden oluştur
reconstructed_audio = reconstruct_audio_from_mfcc(predicted_mfcc[0, ..., 0], sample_rate_clean)

Terminal Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python\Noise Filter.py", line 81, in <module>
    reconstructed_audio = reconstruct_audio_from_mfcc(predicted_mfcc[0, ..., 0], sample_rate_clean)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Python\Noise Filter.py", line 74, in reconstruct_audio_from_mfcc
    mel_spec = librosa.feature.inverse.mfcc_to_mel(mfcc.T)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\atabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\librosa\feature\inverse.py", line 278, in mfcc_to_mel
    logmel = scipy.fftpack.idct(mfcc, axis=-2, type=dct_type, norm=norm, n=n_mels)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\atabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\_realtransforms.py", line 440, in idct
    return _pocketfft.dct(x, type, n, axis, norm, overwrite_x)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\atabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\_pocketfft\realtransforms.py", line 31, in _r2r
    tmp, copied = _fix_shape_1d(tmp, n, axis)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\atabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\_pocketfft\helper.py", line 149, in _fix_shape_1d
    return _fix_shape(x, (n,), (axis,))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\atabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\scipy\fft\_pocketfft\helper.py", line 124, in _fix_shape
    if x.shape[ax] >= n:
       ~~~~~~~^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range


This seems to be an uncovered edge case or so in librosa. You could open a github issue for that one. Try to find out when it occurs and when not.
